# GitHub Services Jenkins plugin branch name

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, webhooks

I have a Jenkins CI and GitHub service for Jenkins GitHub plugin. I want to specify the name of the Branch in the URL that GitHub will invoke. Is there a way to do that. Now my URL looks like `BRANCH=master` is there syntax like `BRANCH=$BRANCH` to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer from GitHub support team. There is no such option in the webhooks, but the name of the branch is inside the payload of the call that GitHub makes. A solution is to modify the GitHub plugin for Jenkins and to give it access to the webhooks from the General settings that Jenkins provide. Then you can use the `$GIT_BRANCH` environmental variable to check the name of the branch.

Comment: Can you please provide more details of this solution? I got the same problem need to address now. Thank you!

Comment: Here in the future I still couldn't find a solution for this.